# Kubernetes Service Mesh(es) with SCTP support

Tags: kubernetes

I'm looking for any Kubernetes Service Mesh(es) with SCTP support, is there any so? Maybe someone already faced such issues?

Comment: Have you thought about Istio? What did  you try? Have you searched for any information online?

Comment: Yes @mdobrucki I did my research. Istio does not have SCTP support